# Self-Signed certificate install on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, ssl, self-signed

I have two servers on which I will access from an iPad using https.

Server-A website is in IIS. 
Server-B website is Java.

I have created two self-signed certificates, 
one for server-A using OpenSSL 
and one for Server-B using keytool.

When I install the certificates on the iPad, the OpenSSL created certificate installs fine and becomes verified, and I can connect successfully on Server-A website using https.

However the self-signed certificate created with keytool stays "not verified" after I install it on the iPad.
Can anyone help me diagnose or fix this issue? thanks.

Comment: The reason why it comes up with Not verified is because it is self-signed. Only a certificate issued from a Trusted CA would come up with Verified

Comment: both are self-signed, and the one created with  openSSL appears "verified", only the one created with keytool does not appear as verfied